# Boot hangs after "Checking battery state..."

Tags: intel-graphics, boot-failure

The boot process of my installation hangs after the **Checking battery state...** message. I can continue to boot using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, then logging in, and typing `startx`. After that everything works as expected, but this is irritating.

Reading around, this error appears to be reasonably common, however it is normally associated with nvidia drivers/etc. whereas I qm using an Intel chipset.

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: did you solve your problem? If so, please mark some answer as accepted or provide your solution. If not, please provide more info in your post. Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: This was fixed by an upgrade to the Intel drivers that followed shortly afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but try going into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and changing the device driver to `vesa`. (`vesa` is a generic video driver that works with most video cards)

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem when something went wrong with my nvidia drivers.

1. Wait to the checking battery state comes up.
2. Try to go to a terminal login screen by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.
3. Then remove the nvidia driver by typing:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-173 nvidia-current
   ```
4. Restart by typing:

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the backup `xorg.conf`!

It took me forever to find the right answer, but in the `/etc/X11` folder there should be a backup of the `xorg.conf`

Open a terminal and use `cp` to overwrite the old `xorg.conf` with the backup,  you should no longer hang after this! For example:
`sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

make sure you're wired and not using wireless, i saw so many people with stupid problems because they didn't have an internet connection...