# Startup hangs at "Checking battery state" even though I have no desktop and no battery

Tags: 12.04, boot, startup

There are a bunch of other threads, and one with this exact question ( [Boot hangs after "Checking battery state..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53435/boot-hangs-after-checking-battery-state)) is closed already (this I think was not warranted), but I haven't solved my problem.

Why does ubuntu hang at "Checking battery state..." when I don't even have a laptop or a battery?  I'm using a desktop computer.

Comment: I believe the other question was closed because it had been abandoned by the original user.

Comment: The problem is gone, but I don't know why, perhaps an Ubuntu update?