# Boot fails after "Checking battery state"

Tags: boot, graphics, display-manager

I am on Ubuntu 12.04. As I was working icons on the top bar started disappearing. I tried to switch between the various windows but <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> was not working. I tried using the mouse to switch between windows but to no avail. On rebooting, the screen stops at

> *Checking battery state. insmod: can't read `/usr/local/bin/ztemtApp/ztemtusbserial/ztemt.ko'. No such file or
>   directory.

Output of /var/log/syslog is http://paste.org/59250

I tried the answers given here [Boot hangs after "Checking battery state..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53435/boot-hangs-after-checking-battery-state) .But that doesn't work. I reconfigured lightdm and restarted but that also did not work. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution... same thing happened to me... may be while installing some package it uninstalled gnome-power-manager.

just get into shell by keying in ctrl+alt+F5 or F6 it will take you to login prompt

get in and type

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Volla !!!

everything is fine... you get back your gui.